# Learning Neural Networks with self similarity

Tags: neural-networks, estimation

Consider neural network $$f_\theta:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$ specified by some parameters $\theta$.

We then build a larger neural network again only depending on $\theta$, 
$$g_\theta:\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$$
where the network $g$ is made up of blocks of $f$.

**Example** (a 2-layer $g$)

Define the projection that splits up $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ blocks
$$P_i : \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$
as
$$P_i({\bf x}) = [x_{n.(i-1)+1}, \dots, x_{n.i}]$$
where ${\bf x} = [x_1, \dots, x_{n^2}]$ i.e. $P_1( {\bf x}) = [x_1, \dots,x_n]$.

Now we can define a hidden layer 
$$ h_\theta : \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2} $$ 
as
$$h_\theta({\bf x}) = M (\oplus_{i=1}^n f_\theta(P_i({\bf x})))$$
where $M: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is some known permutation. This finally gives
$$g_\theta({\bf x}) = \oplus_{i=1}^n f_\theta(P_i(h_\theta({\bf x})))$$

**Question**
Is there an efficient way to learn networks of the form of $g$ i.e. made up of smaller networks $f$? (references to papers would be great)

Comment: You basically reuse the weights of $f$ multiple times for $g_{\theta}$. It should be pretty straight forward to write down the math and derive the backprop algorithm for such an architecture. Start with the forward path (FP). For the backward path you just need to derive the FP with respect to $\theta$ and perform gradient descent.